# Compute Engine, Reset or Stop+Start

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform

I have VM in compute Engine running a docker image uploaded to the Container Registry.

If i push a new image with the same name, is "Reset" enough to load that image or should I keep doing stop+Start?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you upload a docker image to the Container Registry, apart from the name, it [would be wise to tag it](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/quickstart#tag_the_image_with_a_registry_name). If you upload another image with the same name, and same tag, it is enough using reset for the VM to use the new image. Upon resetting, you will be using the image with the same name and tag of the image you first used to deploy a VM. If you do not use tags, the new images you push with the same name without tag will be automatically tagged as "latest", and that one will be used after doing "reset" to your VM.

When using tags, upon uploading the new image with same name and tag, the previous image will lose the tag and the newly uploaded will get it.